# I want to find only one word in this through Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have 1K strings like the following which are saved in a String array and I just need the bold words, which are not a constant)'. So wondering what could be the best way.

(descSummary: EME Commercial (Change Request), archived: false, **name: EME Commercial (Change Request)**, uniqueName: EME Commercial (Change Request)(JTS-Sentinel-Id)) (isInitialized: true, internalPublic: true, internalVisibleToMembers: false, internalVisibleToAccessList: false, owningApplicationKey: JTS-Sentinel-Id, internalIsProcessProvider: false)

Please help!

Comment: What is your question? Why do you need a regex for this?

Comment: Hi Tim, I have 1K strings like this which are saved in a String array and I just need 'name: (after the string, which is not a constant)'. So wondering what could be the best way.

Comment: Poor formating, and stack overflow is overflowing with similar questions, so, down-voted. As for your issue, here is the Docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: oops! soory. I have tried editing many times. But I coundn.t help it. =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like you are asking for the text after the string "name: " and before the following comma, so your regex is `/name: ([^,]+)/`

**Update:**

I don't understand why you're using `.replaceAll()`.

You don't need the slashes to delimit the regex when it's in a Java string literal.  Many people, like me, use the slashes to set it off in ordinary text.

If you want to display the segment you have marked in bold, then you want something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name: ([^,]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str.toString());
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

`.group(0)` returns the entire string that matched the pattern.  `.group(1)` returns the string that matches the first "captured" group in parentheses, the `([^,]+)` part.

And why are you calling `.toString()` on `str`?  The name of that variable suggests that it is a String already.

Comment: Hi David -- I think there is something wrong with it. Can you check it once again please?

Comment: Yes, definitely it was wrong.  I have edited.  You can click the "just now" link to see the change.

Comment: Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("/name: ([^,]+)/");
Matcher matcher = replace.matcher(str.toString());
System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("\t"));

Do you think the code is right? I use to get the entire string.